# ¿Cómo soluciono el fallo de "error al ejecutar 'add' en IDBObjectStore"?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, indexeddb

[![este es el fallo

```
var agregar= almacen.add({clave:clave,name:name,fiscalName:fiscalName,phone:phone,cif:cif,domain:domain,type:type,fecha:fecha});
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcud1.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcud1.jpg)

Comment: Haces una pregunta a medias y sin contexto:
¿Qué error te da? ¿Cuál es el contexto? ¿Qué tipo de dato es almacén?... 
Reformula o aclara tu pregunta para contestar, y mejor si es después de ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var bd;
function iniciar(){
  zonadatos= document.getElementById("zonadatos");// creamos donde se veran los datos
  boton= document.getElementById("grabar");// creamos botón
  boton.addEventListener("click",agregarobjeto,false);
  var solicitud= indexedDB.open("bbddClientes");//creamos bbdd
  solicitud.onsuccess=function(e){ //si funciona bbdd la guarda en bd
      bd=e.target.result;
  }
  solicitud.onupgradeneeded=function(e){//si actualiza se crea tabla
      bd=e.target.result;
      bd.createObjectStore("clientes",{keyPath:"clave"});
  }

}
function agregarobjeto(){
    var clave=document.getElementById("clave").value;
     var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
     var fiscalName=document.getElementById("fiscalName").value;
     var phone=document.getElementById("phone").value;
     var cif=document.getElementById("cif").value;
     var domain=document.getElementById("domain").value;
     var type=document.getElementById("type").value;
     var fecha=document.getElementById("fecha").value;
     var transaccion=bd.transaction(["clientes"],"readwrite");//especificamos lectura/escritura para tabla
     var almacen= transaccion.objectStore("clientes");
     var agregar= almacen.add({clave:clave,name:name,fiscalName:fiscalName,phone:phone,cif:cif,domain:domain,type:type,fecha:fecha});
     document.getElementbyId("clave").value="" ;
     document.getElementbyId("name").value="" ;//resetear info 
      document.getElementbyId("fiscalName").value="";
      document.getElementbyId("phone").value="";
      document.getElementbyId("cif").value="";
      document.getElementbyId("domain").value="";
      document.getElementbyId("type").value="";
      document.getElementbyId("fecha").value="";
     agregar.addEventListener("success",mostrar,false);//evento de escucha en agregar,si es success(exito) lo muestra
    }
function mostrar(){
zonadatos.innerHTML="";//para que aparezca en html
   var transaccion= bd.transaction(["clientes"],"readonly");//solo lectura
   var almacen= transaccion.objectStore("clientes");
   var cursor=almacen.openCursor();
   cursor.addEventListener("success",mostrarDatos,false);
}
function mostrarDatos(e){
    var cursor= e.target.result;//guarda cursor(que está guardado en e) 
    if(cursor){
        zonadatos.innerHTML+="<div>"+cursor.value.clave+"-"+cursor.value.name+"-"+cursor.value.fiscalName+"-"+cursor.value.phone+"-"+cursor.value.cif+"-"+cursor.value.domain+"-"+cursor.value.type+"-"+cursor.value.fecha+"<div>";
        cursor.continue();    
    } 
}

window.addEventListener("load",iniciar,false);
```

Este es el codigo del archivo indexed.js donde me indica en la imagen que adjunté al hacer la pregunta que hay un fallo en línea 26 ¿Cómo se soluciona este fallo?, es decir, "error al ejecutar add en objectstore"

```html
<body> 
  <div id="contentenedor"> 
      <section  class="center-content">
              <p>Clave (id):<br><input type="text" maxlength="1" id="clave" name="clave" class="field"/></p>
              <p>Nombre:<br><input type="text"  id="name" name="name" class="field" /></p>
              <p>Nombre Fiscal:<br><input type="text"  id="fiscalName" name="fiscalName" class="field" /></p>
              <p>Teléfono:<br><input type="text"  id="phone" name="phone" class="field"/></p>  
              <p>CIF:<br><input type="text"  id="cif" name="cif" class="field"/></p>
              <p>Dominio:<br><input type="text"  id="domain" name="domain" class="field"/></p>
              <p>Tipo:<br><input type="text"  id="type" name="type" class="field"/></p>
              <p><input type="datetime-local" value="2022-05-05T12:30" id="fecha" class="field"></p>
                <p><button type="submit" name="grabar" id="grabar" class="btn btn-green">Grabar</button></p>
        </section>
     <section id="zonadatos" class="center-content">
          Aquí aparecerían los datos
        </section>
   </div>
</body>
```

Estee es el body del html del formulario. Lo que pretendo es que aparezcan debajo del formulario los datos que se introducen en el formulario pero no aparece debido a ese fallo que comento.

Comment: Si sos el mismo usuario que formuló la pregunta, [solicitá la combinación de las cuentas](/contact). Esto debe ser una edición de la pregunta.